# By the power of MergeAdapter, StickyListHeaders and ListViewAnimations combined I'm captain Android

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, expandable, commonsware-cwac

Has anyone joined MergeAdapter, StickyListHeaders and ListViewAnimations android libraries?

My needs are:

- multiple ListViews in one vertically scrolled view
- heterogenous item views
- multiple list items separated by headers, which should be sticky
- ability to expand some list items
- drag'n'drop some of them
- support android 14+

My extras:

- rely on CursorAdapters

Cherrypick:

- sometimes my very top header (which is separate view not part of my list and I'll prefer it to stay that way) need to slide a bit over to the top; my combined list should follow but in the same time animate extend of it's height in order to always be attached to a bottom.

Mentioned libraries were:

- MergeAdapter - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge
- StickyListHeaders - https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
- ListViewAnimations - https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Please give me some hope if it's possible and some useful tips how to avoid pitfalls. Maybe I should use some other libs. Or I'll just have to write that myself :(

====EDITED====

In the end I have managed to build a stub of what I was hoping to do (in early 2014). It is functional expandable and draggable listview and adapter lib with nice animations (no sticky headers yet). Here's repo:

- https://github.com/fada21/HydraListAndroid

Since RecyclerView is now available there's no need to use overcomplicated listview code. Here is quick switch guide - http://andraskindler.com/2014/11/22/migrating-to-recyclerview/.

Comment: +1 for "Or I'll just have to write that myself"

Comment: Eventually I'll try. I've seen here -> [stickylistheaders-and-mergeadapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310417/stickylistheaders-and-mergeadapter) that part of it is possible but I'd love to have animations. I'm afraid I'll be very ugly to handle.

Comment: I will be stunned if combining all of those will work.

Answer (score 1):

From the ListViewAnimations wiki:
http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#getting-started

> ListViewAnimations also supports appearance animations on
>   StickyListHeaderListViews. You must wrap your AnimationAdapter in a
>   StickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator:

```
StickyListHeadersListView listView = (...); AlphaInAnimationAdapter
animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
StickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator stickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator =
new StickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator(animationAdapter);
stickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator.setStickyListHeadersListView(listView);
listView.setAdapter(stickyListHeadersAdapterDecorator);
```

> Just like with the normal ListView, you can use any implementation of
>   the AnimationAdapter class.

In combination with the solution from [StickyListHeaders and MergeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310417/stickylistheaders-and-mergeadapter) the uber-mergeadapter should be a possiblity :P

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating an adapter to handle the headers.

Using the adapter class:

```
StickyHeaderMergeAdapter stickyHeaderMergeAdapter = new StickyHeaderMergeAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_header, R.id.text1);
stickyHeaderMergeAdapter.addAdapter(
                myTypcalAdapter,
                R.string.stringName
);
this.stickyHeaderListView.setAdapter(stickyHeaderMergeAdapter);
```

The Adapter class:

```
package mypackagename.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter;

public class StickyHeaderMergeAdapter extends MergeAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {
    private final LinkedHashMap<ListAdapter,Integer> adapterViewHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private final Context context;
    private final int headerLayoutId;
    private final int headerLayoutTextId;

    public StickyHeaderMergeAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int headerLayoutId, @IdRes int headerLayoutTextId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.headerLayoutId = headerLayoutId;
        this.headerLayoutTextId = headerLayoutTextId;
    }

    public void addAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter, @StringRes int stringId) {
        super.addAdapter(listAdapter);
        this.adapterViewHashMap.put(listAdapter, stringId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("You should use addAdapter(ListAdapter, View)");
    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = View.inflate(this.context, this.headerLayoutId, null);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(this.headerLayoutTextId)).setText(
                this.adapterViewHashMap.get(this.getAdapter(position))
        );

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int i) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = this.getAdapter(i);
        if (!this.adapterViewHashMap.containsKey(listAdapter))
            return 0;

        return this.adapterViewHashMap.get(listAdapter);
    }
}
```